# CSV changes date and time format while writing in csv python?

Tags: python, datetime

Basically I have date/time in following format `2018-9-10 16:5:21` but when I write this to a csv file it converts the date/time format to `10/09/2018  4:05:21 PM`

Script:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
timetoout = str(now.year)+"-"+str(now.month)+"-"+str(now.day)+" "+str(now.hour)+":"+str(now.minute)+":"+str(now.second)
spamwriter.writerow([x] + [x+", "+x] + [x] + [x] + [x] + [timetoout] + [x] + [x])
print(timetoout)
```

But in console I am seeing the approperiate formate.

All replies are much appreciated.

Comment: So just to be clear, when printed to the console, the dates are in the CORRECT format? If you are viewing the CSV in something like excel, it will sometimes convert the dates to a different format while viewing the file.

Comment: Open your file on notepad and see its the same format.

Comment: This is off-topic but consider using the following to replace the second line in your code: `timeout = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`; other custom formats can be found [here](https://www.foragoodstrftime.com/)